# .NET 4.0: Is it possible to call ConvertAll for IList<>?

Tags: .net, generics, .net-4.0

'ConvertAll' is not implemented for IList, Am I right? Is there any workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the actual type? Perhaps it is already List<> ?

Comment: (note that there is a big difference between `IList` and `IList<T>`)

Comment: As Alastair notes, `.Select(...)` is the way to go here

Comment: Actual object is something custom, that only implement IList<>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`IList<T>` does not define a method called `ConvertAll()`. You can see the definition here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx

There is a method on the concrete implementation `List<T>`; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx

You can replicate this behaviour using the LINQ statement `.Select()`.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use a `System.Collections.Generic.List` to have a `.ConvertAll()` method in the base.

`IList` does not implement `.ConvertAll()`.

If you MUST use an `IList`, you could always write your own `.ConvertAll()` method.